# SQL query null value replaced based on another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

So I have query to return data and a row number using ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY) and I place it into a temp table. The initial output looks the screenshot:

[image: screenshot out output].

From here I need to, in the bt_newlabel column, replace the nulls respectively. So Rownumber 1-4 would be in progress, 5-9 would be underwriting, 10-13 would be implementation, and so forth.

I am hitting a wall trying to determine how to do this. Thanks for any help or input of how I would go about this.

Comment: Sorry, not in progress, but 1-4 would be pre-underwriting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to assign groups, and then the value.  Such as:

```
select t.*, max(bt_newlabel) over (partition by grp) as new_newlabel
from (select t.*, count(bt_newlabel) over (order by bt_stamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

The group is simply the number of known values previously seen in the data.

You can update the field with:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(bt_newlabel) over (partition by grp) as new_newlabel
      from (select t.*, count(bt_newlabel) over (order by bt_stamp) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set bt_newlabel = new_newlabel
    where bt_newlabel is null;
```

Comment: That is perfect. I have been beating my head against the wall trying to come up with a way to do this...you have parted the trees and I can now see the forest!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are trying to do, this is the type of update you need to do on your temp table:

```
--This will update rows 1-4 to 'Pre-Underwritting'

UPDATE temp_table SET bt_newlabel = 'Pre-Underwritting'
WHERE rownumber between 
1 AND (SELECT TOP 1 rownumber FROM temp_table WHERE bt_oldlabel = 'Pre-Underwritting');

--This will update rows 5-9 to 'Underwritting'

UPDATE temp_table SET bt_newlabel = 'Underwritting'
WHERE rownumber between 
(SELECT TOP 1 rownumber FROM temp_table WHERE bt_oldlabel = 'Pre-Underwritting')
AND
(SELECT TOP 1 rownumber FROM temp_table WHERE bt_oldlabel = 'Underwritting');

--This will update rows 10-13 to 'Implementation'

UPDATE temp_table SET bt_newlabel = 'Implementation'
WHERE rownumber between 
(SELECT TOP 1 rownumber FROM temp_table WHERE bt_oldlabel = 'Underwritting')
AND
(SELECT TOP 1 rownumber FROM temp_table WHERE bt_oldlabel = 'Implementation');
```

I made a working Fiddle to check out the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1cae2/1/3